# Application hangs on button segue with Xcode 7.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, xcode-storyboard

I recently upgraded to El Capitan with Xcode 7.0.1. I started a new iOS project with a simple start button and segue to another View Controller. My program runs without any Xcode errors, but when I press the start button it grays out and hangs:

[image]

Here is my Xcode storyboard:
[image]

NOTE: I have not written any code yet, this is all created via the storyboard.

If anyone knows what is wrong, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found a bug on the Apple Forum [https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18691][1]

"Sep 23, 2015 2:15 PM
(in response to rwhtech)
Thank you!!!

With a view controller, inside a UIPageViewController, with tons of different types of views, it took me two days to get to your issue and figure out I had the same problem!

Work around:
Delete the text content inside UITextView, Text in Story Board, making it empty...

It used to work up to xCode 6...."

Not a solution, but at least my application does not hang. I suppose you can program the text in Swift.